# Missing items eventually array list

Tags: c++, c, arrays, memory, memory-management

Sometimes, my list "dissapear" with some items.

Debugging, i realize that happen eventually.

So i believe its a problem with how memory was allocated.

Problem:

need to get some hash from a file, and insert into a list to deal with later.

.txt:

```
####
....
....
....

....
.##.
.##.
....

####
....
....
....
```

I inserted into a list an array with lines and values per hash like:

example hash 2:

```
line[0][0] = 1
line[0][1] = 2
line[1][0] = 1
line[1][1] = 2
```

About hashes:

With the first hash on textfile, sometimes, if i use more than one, he disappear.

With the second hash, sometimes he disappear with the first array.

I dont see that happening with differents hashes.

The problem is, on previous interaction i got the array list correctly, so when i go on, part of array disappear.

All code below

[Code to deal with everything](https://pastebin.com/PAe7Y2Ch)

Outputs: Starting from hash 1 on .txt

Output -> Hash 2
Starting with hash 1 and 2

```
I: 0  J: 0, tmp[0][0]: Value: 0
I: 0  J: 1, tmp[0][1]: Value: 1
I: 0  J: 2, tmp[0][2]: Value: 2
I: 0  J: 3, tmp[0][3]: Value: 3
Next from list
I: 0  J: 0, tmp[0][0]: Value: 1
I: 0  J: 1, tmp[0][1]: Value: 2
I: 1  J: 0, tmp[1][0]: Value: 1
I: 1  J: 1, tmp[1][1]: Value: 2
```

Thats means, he did the allocation and got the array correctly.

But when we go to the next interaction, with a next hash, part of that array disappear.

-> Output hash 2 + 1

Next interaction, to get now hash n3

```
I: 0  J: 0, tmp[0][0]: Value: 0
I: 0  J: 1, tmp[0][1]: Value: 1
I: 0  J: 2, tmp[0][2]: Value: 2
I: 0  J: 3, tmp[0][3]: Value: 3

Next
I: 1  J: 0, tmp[1][0]: Value: 1
I: 1  J: 1, tmp[1][1]: Value: 2

Next
I: 0  J: 0, tmp[0][0]: Value: 0
I: 0  J: 1, tmp[0][1]: Value: 1
I: 0  J: 2, tmp[0][2]: Value: 2
I: 0  J: 3, tmp[0][3]: Value: 3
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve] with the code that you are using.

Comment: I got it. Problem is with realloc function. i created my own realloc and for some reason he is "eating" part of my array. Didnt solve yet, but i know is from there

Comment: sorry, i know was not a good post, but yeah, was a big bug and i was struggling myself for last 2 days

Comment: My realloc: https://pastebin.com/iKVHnGRm

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved.

I've created my own realloc function before.

```
char    *ft_realloc(char *str, size_t size)
{
    char *new_str;
    int i = 0;

    new_str = malloc(size);
    ft_bzero(new_str,size);
    if(!new_str)
        return (0);
    if(str)
    {
        ft_strncpy(new_str, str, size);
        free(str);
    }
    return new_str;
}
```

Solution, set to null before free.

```
str = NULL
free(str)
```